# JavaFX 8 Alert not showing after changing application

Tags: java, javafx-8

## tl;dr

If I click the application in my Mac's dock first, then choose to show Alert from app's system tray menu. Alert shows. No problem.
But, if I choose another application (let's say Chrome). Then choose to show Alert from app's system tray menu, then Alert won't be brought in front.

That is, I have to RECLICK the application on the dock, then Alert shows.

## details

I have a JavaFX application, and put it in System Tray with Menu.

Menu has different things:

```
final java.awt.PopupMenu popup = new java.awt.PopupMenu();
popup.add(aboutItem);
popup.addSeparator();
popup.add(settingsItem);
popup.addSeparator();
popup.add(printJobsItem);
popup.add(exitItem);
trayIcon.setPopupMenu(popup);
```

Where each item has an action listener set:

```
aboutItem.addActionListener(event -> Platform.runLater(this::showAboutDialog));

settingsItem.addActionListener(event -> Platform.runLater(this::showSettingsStage));

//etc
```

## Question

1. Why do I have to 'activate' the app (by choosing on the OS's dock) so that showAboutDialog's alert to show up?
2. If we're using Stage, then this is no problem. You can switch to another application or whatever and by the time you click "Settings" from the app's tray menu, then Setting Stage is shown.

### EDIT-1

just tested on Windows 10, this is NOT happening. But on OS X El Capitan, it's still happening.

Comment: Just wondering if you have any specific reasons for using `java.awt.PopupMenu` inside a JavaFX application..

Comment: Not really. Still learning and probably not aware of other alternatives.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha There is no Tray support in JavaFX yet. See https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8092115 and https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/e231e89e8d36ef4e5d8a

Comment: The thing is if it's Stage based (not Alert-based), it works fine by bringing the stage in front.